# How to recover GRUB after upgrade from 9.10 to 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, server, upgrade, grub2

After I have done an upgrade from Ubuntu 9.10 to Ubuntu server 10.04, the server stops with a GRUB rescue message, how can I recover my GRUB without reinstalling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to restore GRUB2 by following [these detailed instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20GRUB%202).

Comment: I guess there is no work around a live CD so I've just burned a CD and recovered my grub with this. (You have to take a desktop edition (no terminal in server CD))